# Cast from 'NSMutableArray' to unrelated type '[String]' always fails

Tags: swift2, type-conversion

I'm writing a QuizApp in Swift and there's this piece of code that is driving me crazy.

I have the following variables declared before my UIViewController class:

```
var questionsList:[String] = []
var answersList:[NSMutableArray] = []
```

I do read a .plist file loading its content:

```
    let dictRoot = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename", ofType: "plist")!)
    questionsList = (dictRoot?.allKeys)! as! [String]
    answersList = (dictRoot?.allValues)! as! [NSMutableArray]
```

I have a generateRandomQuestion function which goes like this:

```
func generateRandomQuestion() {
    let randomQuestionIndex = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(questionsList.count))
    randomQuestion = "\(questionsList[randomQuestionIndex])"
    answersToRandomQuestion = (answersList[randomQuestionIndex]) as! [String]
```

unfortunately the casting to the NSMutableArray to the [String] always fails...

Any hint on how convert it without messing around?

(I tried the flatMap but it doesn't work...)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use mutable Foundation collection types unless you have absolutely no choice.

Use the native Swift type.

```
var answersList = [[String]]()
...
answersList = (dictRoot?.allValues)! as! [[String]]
```

Comment: don't know how to say THANK YOU. You saved my day! Really appreciate!
p.s. tried to vote but don't have enough reputation to make it visible :-(

Comment: But I think you are able to accept the answer with rep 1

Comment: True! 